# Verb describing chainsaw making that bursting sound when you push the throttle trigger

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

With the positive meaning, if it possible, just so I didn't have to use adverbs like happily. The only thing I came up- buzzed. Thank you.

Comment: Patrick Bateman, is...is that you?

Comment: blip ... Blip ... BLA-A-A-T.

Answer (score 3):

Two-cycle, or four?  Anyhow, consider *[brattle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brattle#Verb)*, a verb that means “To rattle; to make a scampering noise”, with etymology “Apparently imitative, probably under influence of break + rattle”.  I don't know what a scampering noise is, but believe brattle suggests the right sort of sound.

To *[rev up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rev_up#English)* an engine is “To increase the speed of an engine”, so *revving up* may be appropriate too, along with the less-well-known *poppity-popping*.

Comment: watch out we got a chainsaw-enthusiast over here) I may be wrong (and I probably am) but bratlling (?) sound seems to mean sound produced by other things influenced by an object moving. For example- you could brattle with a pack full of tin cans if you are rummaging hastily through it. I guess I'm looking for the verb that means to make sound of suddenly increasing speed? Does it make any sense? Again, my English is potato. Can whizzed be used? Or does it mean to urinate? )

Answer (score 1):

How about *roared*?  It connotes power more strongly than *buzzed* does, but is still a word in common usage.

Comment: I just don't think that roar is the right sound, seems like it should be something more high pitch. But thank you.

Answer (score -1):

How about growled or ripped???